# I want the images not to be repeated, just to change the order randomly

Tags: javascript

I have this code from codepen, but when loading the images it repeats them, and what I want to do is keep them appearing randomly, but not repeat them.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Random image grid</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->

<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    for (i=1; i<8; i++){    
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('<img class="sq" src="ads/ads-' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 7)+1) + '.jpg">').appendTo('body');
            }, i * 1);
        }(i));
    };
}, false);
```

Any idea how I can do it, I'm kind of new to js, ​​I'm just learning

Comment: can you add a link to the codepen project you referenced?

Comment: I suppose you have to save the already shown ids in an array, and skip the image if the array already includes that id

Comment: are you looking for 8 random images appearing on the screen at once, or 1 random, randomly changing image?

Comment: While it may work without, it is recommended to user the 'var' or 'let' keyword to declare your variable inside your for loop.

Comment: @GuyNachshon https://codepen.io/dhobson7/pen/wxBmya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating random numbers in each iteration, generate the array of possible numbers (0..7), shuffle them, and then use that shuffled array to produce the images.

Side node: as you use jQuery, use it with its full potential:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
    }
    return a;
}

$(function() {
    let nums = shuffle([...Array(8).keys()]);
    
    (function loop() {
        if (!nums.length) return;
        let i = nums.pop() + 1;
        $("<img>", {
            class: "sq",
            src: `ads/ads-${i}.jpg`,
            alt: i
        }).appendTo("body");
        setTimeout(loop, 100);
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked great. Could you tell me how I can do it to show those images in some div, as it is in the code it only shows it in the whole body

Comment: Just include the div in the static html and refer to it in the `appendTo` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with all the images you want to add. Then while there is at least one image, you add it to the screen and remove it from the array at a given interval.

```
 document.addEventListener(

  "DOMContentLoaded",
  function () {
    const imgs = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
      imgs.push(`ads/ads-${i}.jpg`);
    }

    const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
      while (imgs.length > 0) {
        const img = imgs[Math.floor(Math.random() * imgs.length)];

      $(
        `<img class="sq" src="${img}">`
      ).appendTo("body");

        imgs.splice(imgs.indexOf(img), 1);
      }

      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, 100);
  },
  false
);
```